# apply diff() only on consecutive days

Tags: r, date, diff

I have the following data and I would like to apply the function `diff()` only on consecutive days: `diff(data$ch, differences = 1, lag = 1)` returns the differences between all consecutive values of `ch` (23-12, 4-23, 78-4, 120-78, 94-120, ...). I would like the `diff()` function to return `NA` when the dates are not consecutive. The output I am trying to obtain from the data below is:

```
11, -19, 74, NA, -26, NA, -34, 39, NA
```

Is there anyone who knows how I can do that?

```
Date        ch
2013-01-01  12
2013-01-02  23
2013-01-03  4
2013-01-04  78
2013-01-10  120
2013-01-11  94
2013-02-26  36
2013-02-27  2
2013-02-28  41
2003-03-05  22
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do these in `base R` without installing any external packages.

Assuming that the 'Date' column is of `Date` class, we take the `diff` of the 'Date' and based on whether the difference between adjacent elements are greater than 1 or not, we can create a grouping index ('indx') by taking the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of the logical vector.

```
 indx <- cumsum(c(TRUE,abs(diff(df1$Date))>1))
```

In the second step, we can use `ave` with 'indx' as the grouping vector, and take the `diff` of 'ch'.  The length of output of `diff` will be 1 less than the length of the 'ch' column.  So we can append `NA` to make the lengths same.

```
 ave(df1$ch, indx, FUN=function(x) c(diff(x),NA))
 #[1]  11 -19  74  NA -26  NA -34  39  NA  NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 
15715, 15716, 15762, 15763, 15764, 12116), class = "Date"), ch = c(12L, 
23L, 4L, 78L, 120L, 94L, 36L, 2L, 41L, 22L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"ch"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! I tried to apply this also with the function Delt():
ave(df1$ch, indx, FUN=function(x) c(Delt(x),NA))
but it returns some warning messages that I don't understand:
"In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN"

Comment: @stem What is `Delt`?

Comment: Perhaps, would something like `ans = diff(df1$ch); ans[abs(diff(df1$Date)) > 1] = NA; ans` suffice? Or it seems a bit "fragile"?

Comment: @alexis_laz looks promising.  I have to test it.

Comment: @akrun Delt() is a function belonging to the library quantmod that calculates the k-period percent difference within one series: 
(x2 - x1)/x1 
http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/Delt.html

Comment: @stem You should post that as a separate question as the solution here solves for the example you provided.

Answer (score 5):

The following just "...returns `NA` when the dates are not consecutive", unless there are tricky cases that it won't account for:

```
replace(diff(df1$ch), abs(diff(df1$Date)) > 1, NA)
#[1]  11 -19  74  NA -26  NA -34  39  NA
```

Comment: In certain cases, using `which` would make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with the libraries `lubridate` and `dplyr`

If you don't have them do this once `install.packages("dplyr");install.packages("lubridate")`

***Code***

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data$Date <- ymd(data$Date)
data2 <- data %>% mutate(diff=ifelse(Date==lag(Date)+days(1), ch-lag(ch), NA))
```

***Data***

```
data <- 
  data.frame(Date=c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-10", 
                    "2013-01-11", "2013-01-26", "2013-01-27", "2013-01-28", "2013-03-05"),
               ch=c(12, 23, 4, 78, 120, 94, 36, 2, 41, 22))
```